# ERROR: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""U'?

Tags: c++, xilinx, vivado, zynq

I am using ARM v7 g++ compiler on Vivado and SDK 2017.4. I had the same code working without any problem, but now it is throwing this error after changing something which is not related with this, apparently. I have undone the changes but it still complains.

```
../../MicroZed_design9_bsp/ps7_cortexa9_0/include/xparameters.h:557:40: error: unable to find numeric literal operator 'operator""U'
#define XPAR_AXI_TIMER_0_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ 1e+08U
```

Where is this coming from?

Comment: It's coming from the `U` at the end of `1e+08U`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`U` is not valid at the end of a floating point literal. Valid suffixes are `f` or `F` to indicate a `float`, `l` or `L` to indicate a `long double`, and no suffix to default to `double`. `U` to indicate `unsigned` can only be used at the end of an integer literal.

So `1e+08U` is not valid because `1e+08` is the syntax for a floating point literal. Exponential notation can't be used for integers. If you want an `unsigned long` integer, write `100000000UL`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Barmar. I see. The problem is that this file is autogenerated by the software and it compiled before. So I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Ok, I have found a _temporary_ solution. I do not know how it happened because is Vivado who generated this line, which is linked to the AXI clock (100MHz).

`#define XPAR_AXI_TIMER_0_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ 1e+08U`.

I have removed the exponent and now it compiles.

`#define XPAR_AXI_TIMER_0_CLOCK_FREQ_HZ 100000000U`.

However, I have no clue why the code compiled before. I have not changed the AXI clock from the previous version to this one.

Thanks @Barmar for your answer.